# fastest way to transfer images over internet

Tags: video, web

I'm working on a project where I need to transfer lots of images with the lowest latency possible (real time remote viewing). With jpg compression I have about 160kB / frame of data to transfer.

I have full control over both client and server implementation, but I would like to use a web browser for the client if possible for ease of distribution.

What is the best technology/approach for this? Ideas I'm considering so far:

1. static file server (nginx), html/js to load images
2. binary websockets
3. server side rendering with some sort of low latency video encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried websockets with binaryjs, results were fantastic compared to static files served over http.